# Where To Begin? Working with ArcMap and arcpy (Exporting Subset Maps from a Base Map)

Tags: cursor, mapping, gis, arcpy

This is only my 2nd post on here so I apologize if I missed something.  I have looked around for my answer a lot, but I am a little overwhelmed as even where to begin.  I am in an introductory Python and GIS course and we have a final project as the semester ends.  We spent the first 9 of 11 weeks learning Python basics but only spent 2 weeks covering anything ArcGIS (arcpy) related.

My task at hand is this:

I have a base map of a county covered with a high resolution raster, divided into regions.  Each region has a city as a point feature in it.  There are a total of 8 cities.  My project is to create a Python script that can export my map as a mdx and/or pdf document and then to pan/zoom in on each individual city point on the map and create and export a sub-map of each city at a much larger scale (zoomed in).  Each map is supposed to be re-fitted with a title and such, but for the most part my primary goal is just to zoom in on a point and export a new map document.

I have spent 1 week working on the basics of cursors and arcpy, but that is as far as my knowledge goes.  From reading it sounds like I will have to utilize arcpy and arcpy.mapping.  I was told by someone I could create a table with fields and use cursors to perform my goal.

Can anyone help point me about where/how to even begin writing this script, where to read, or a foundation script or idea?

I can e-mail anyone the map I have, but the data would be harder, it is 310mb.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's homework, I'm just going to point you at the relevant help pages for your project and let you try to fill in the blanks. I do this *a lot* at work, and so do a lot of other GIS professionals -- automated mapping is one of the most useful ways to combine ArcMap with Python scripts. But learning how to do it is also important ;)

*Side note:* There are going to be some stumbling blocks between "here's the script workflow" and "here's a script" (which, good, you're learning from them) -- I recommend you post on [GIS.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com) instead of StackOverflow to get faster GIS-specific answers.

---

- [ArcPy](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/what-is-arcpy-.htm) is the Python module which enables you to use ArcMap functions within Python scripts. So yes, you'll need ArcPy. (Luckily, it is automatically installed on any machine that has an ArcGIS Desktop installation.) There are dozens of [tutorials and ways to learn ArcPy](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2014/03/26/7-easy-ways-learning-python-arcpy/), but often just trying to replicate your regular Desktop workflow with Python commands is just as effective.
- There are two ways to use Python scripts that relate to a map document (such as this project): as a standalone (e.g. `mapmaker.py` Python script), or within the [ArcMap Python window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/what-is-the-python-window-.htm). Some things are easier from within the window, but having a standalone script is nice for saving your work (or turning it in) -- plan ahead which you'll use. Generally the script workflow will be the same, but variables will be different; when asking GIS.SE questions, be specific about whether your script is standalone or not.
- Creating maps from Python is a two-part process.

  First, you must design a map layout that has the information you want -- north arrow, title, data frame, etc. This is the basis for what can be exported by your Python script. So do your cartography, and save that MXD file. The script can't be built without an MXD to refer to.

  Second, your script needs to use that MXD to generate a bunch of PDFs. This is done with the [arcpy.mapping](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/introduction-to-arcpy-mapping.htm) library. There is a decent [tutorial](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/getting-started-with-arcpy-mapping-tutorial.htm) (from Esri) that walks you through the typical steps.
- To go through cities one at a time, you'll probably want a [SearchCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) combined with a [Select Layer By Attribute](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-attribute.htm). For each city name (or other unique identifier), you need to create a new selection, zoom to the selected point, and then [export a pdf](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttopdf.htm). Pseudocode:

  ```
  with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(city_layer, ["CITY_NAME"]) as cursor:
      for row in cursor:
          # select city_layer based on row[0]
          # zoom to that city (ref. arcpy.mapping commands)
          # export a map (ref. arcpy.mapping commands)
  ```

Comment: Thanks so much Erica!  This already has taken an edge off of my anxiety.